# App icon not showing on iPad Pro (12.9 inch) 2nd Generation ONLY

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

My app icon will appear on all the other iPad and iPhone devices.
On the iPad Pro (12.9 inch) 2nd Generation, it does not appear, but the default grid icon appears.

If I use Alternate Icons, these appear on the same iPad.
I have a full set of Icons in Assets.xcassets for my app.

Again: All the icons work on all other devices.

Comment: try to make icons from this side and first its requirement. https://makeappicon.com/

Comment: Strange, this happened to me as well. I have an iPhone-only app that had the default grid icon on the iPad. Strangely, it suddenly got fixed without modifying the app.

Comment: MRizwan33: Thanks for the comment, but that is exactly the site that my icons are baked from!

Answer (score 0):

As happened to the4kman, the problem seemed to solve itself. I did mess with the icon that I was using, so may be that helped solve it.

I also had a problem with the launch screen storyboard image being cached with an old image, and this was only cured by reseting the device! But now all working.